# Nginx virtual hosts, site1 works but site2 receives 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

- Ubuntu 14.10
- Nginx 1.6.2
- Running PHP5-FPM
- Both sites are Wordpress
- Both files are symlinked to the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled directory
- Have restarted entire server, and ran *service nginx restart* and *service php5-fpm restart*

Site1 works fine

**Site2 attempts to load, but sits on "Waiting for site2.com...." until it ends in a 504 Gateway Time-out**

Configs are below (these are the only 2 files in sites-available and sites-enabled)

site1.com

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/site1.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name site1.com *.site1.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
     }
```

}

site2.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/site2.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name site2.com *.site2.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
     }
```

}

nginx.conf

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes 4;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
            worker_connections 4096;
            multi_accept on;
    }

    http {

            ##
            # Basic Settings
            ##

            #sendfile on;
            #tcp_nopush on;
            #tcp_nodelay on;
            #keepalive_timeout 10;
            types_hash_max_size 2048;
            server_tokens off;

            # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
            # server_name_in_redirect off;

            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            default_type application/octet-stream;

    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;


            ##
            # Logging Settings
            ##
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log warn;
            #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
            #error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

            ##
            # Gzip Settings
            ##

            gzip on;
            gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    open_file_cache max=2000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 60s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
    open_file_cache_errors off;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    client_body_buffer_size 1m;
    client_body_timeout 15;
    client_header_timeout 15;
    keepalive_timeout 2 2;
    send_timeout 15;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 10s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 120s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 120s;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:

- check nginx access/error logs
- check php5-fpm log  and syslog messages - maybe your site2.com just dies due to php5 script timing out (you have quite low timeout set up in php and script may require some time to process some files, rebuild cache)
- check on you computer if your DNS properly resolve for the site1.com and site2.com if they point to the proper dns entries
- use curl to perform GET request to given server IP (the server you use) and try it with setting HEADER to specify vhost for site1.com and site2.com to see if it works - firs try it from the server itself, then try from remote machine.  Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call
- check if a lot of requests to the site1.com does not saturate php5-fpm worker - this can be avoided by creating different pools in php5-fpm per website